# Using Settings.settings in a windows WPF app (vs2010)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, properties

This is an offline app And I am simply trying to write back to to the Settings.settings file.

In my project under Properties in the file named Settings.settings I add

Name: User, Type: string, Scope:User, Value:Default

After that in my App.xaml.cs file I attempt to read from and write to that value. I have no issue reading from that value, but it seems that it is not even an option to write back.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace StrainTracker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        string userName= StrainTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.User;
        StrainTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.User = "SomethingSilly"; //line 16
        StrainTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();                  //line 17
    }
}
```

Here are the errors generated by visual studio.

```
Error   1   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration ..\Projects\StrainTracker\StrainTracker\App.xaml.cs 16  63  StrainTracker
Error   2   Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration ..\Projects\StrainTracker\StrainTracker\App.xaml.cs 17  55  StrainTracker
Error   3   'StrainTracker.Properties.Settings.Default' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'   ..\Projects\StrainTracker\StrainTracker\App.xaml.cs 16  43  StrainTracker
Error   4   'StrainTracker.Properties.Settings.Default' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'   ..\Projects\StrainTracker\StrainTracker\App.xaml.cs 17  43  StrainTracker
```

I can not for the life of me figure out what the issue is. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider placing the code inside a constructor or some method:

```
public partial class App : Application 
{
    public App()
    { 
        string userName= StrainTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.User;
        StrainTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.User = "SomethingSilly";
        StrainTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks =, any idea why the value does not actually save while in debug mod?

Comment: In the release version it gets saved and in debug doesn't? Sorry, no idea.

Comment: Actually it does not work in debug or release, or a built exe. I dug it acts as though it has changed whole the program is running.

Comment: You know that the [UserScoped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zz7y4375.aspx) setting are stored in `%APPDATA%\YourApplicationName\YourApplicationName.config` (i.e. `C:\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\YourApplicationName\YourApplicationName.config` ? You can't write to the Settings.settings file. That file is not a runtime configuration file, but only part of your application's sources.